# python deep copy and function call

Tags: python, deep-copy

I expect deepcopy to duplicate my object and return a different object id each time it is called since MyClass is mutable, but it does not. Each time the function f() is called, deepcopy returns the same id. I don't know what am I missing here. Here is the code:

```
from copy import deepcopy

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0

obj1 = MyClass()

def f():
    obj_c = deepcopy(obj1)
    print id(obj_c)


# each call prints same id
f() 
f()
```

Comment: It works on my machine

Comment: I don't agree given link answers my question. I am not asking how to override deepcopy.

Comment: @RafalS I am running on python 2.7 interpreter. are you?

Comment: Yeah, now i get the same results

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't agree given link answers my question. I am not asking how to override deepcopy.

Comment: Oh, I see; there you go, updated, sorry about that. Note that you shouldn't use Python 2 now and, if you must use 2.x, you *definitely* shouldn't use old-style classes.

Comment: Yeah, you should inherit from object

Comment: @RafalS No. Inheriting from object did not work, too.

Comment: Im running the same code under python 2.7.17 and I get different results from `id` on copied objects

Comment: my python version is 2.7.16 build fro os x